# Tizen emulator not working on mac (Maveriks)

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-emulator, tizen-studio

I'm having problems to create a virtual machine of the Tizen Emulator Wearable (2.3.1). Everything is installed properly but once I want to create a new virtual machine it return error 133. I'm running Mac OS X (10.9.5).

[image: Error Tizen emulator]

```
JAVA HOME: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
JAVA VENDOR: Oracle Corporation
JAVA VERSION: 1.8.0_40
OS ARCH: x86_64
OS NAME: Mac OS X
OS VERSION: 10.9.5
SWT PLATFROM: cocoa
SWT VERSION: 4527
[2016.8.17 9:1:45.269][INFO][About.printSystemInformation] EmulatorManager Information
Version: 2.4.0_Rev8
Build time: 20160608-1400 (GMT)
Git version: fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
Workspace path: /Users/xruiz/tizen-sdk-data/emulator/vms
Package version: 2.4.199
[2016.8.17 9:1:45.286][INFO][EmulatorManager.main] Start Emulator Manager!!
[2016.8.17 9:1:45.306][INFO][CheckGPU.work] Support GPU: true
[2016.8.17 9:1:45.306][INFO][CheckGPU.work] Gallium: false
[2016.8.17 9:1:45.306][INFO][Overseer$1.run] Overseer [Checkers] is done...
[2016.8.17 9:1:49.844][INFO][NameItem.checkVMName] If you do not need this VM(), delete VM folder.
[2016.8.17 9:1:50.486][INFO][TemplateLoader.loadTemplate] 2.3.1-wearable-circle-template-v2.xml is loaded for 2.3.1-wearable-circle
[2016.8.17 9:1:50.504][WARNING][StandardPlatform.makeItemList] Fail to load ItemListFactory. Image : 2.3.1-wearable-circle
[2016.8.17 9:1:50.504][INFO][StandardPlatform.makeItemList] Use CommonItemListFactory.
[2016.8.17 9:1:50.552][INFO][TemplateLoader.loadTemplate] 2.3.1-wearable-circle-template-v2.xml is loaded for 2.3.1-wearable
[2016.8.17 9:1:50.552][WARNING][StandardPlatform.makeItemList] Fail to load ItemListFactory. Image : 2.3.1-wearable
[2016.8.17 9:1:50.552][INFO][StandardPlatform.makeItemList] Use CommonItemListFactory.
[2016.8.17 9:1:55.643][WARNING][QemuImgProc$1.run] Failed check base image...(from qemu-img)
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libz.1.2.8.dylib
[2016.8.17 9:1:55.644][WARNING][QemuImgProc$1.run] Failed check base image...(from qemu-img)
  Referenced from: /Users/xruiz/tizen-sdk/tools/emulator/bin/qemu-img
[2016.8.17 9:1:55.644][WARNING][QemuImgProc$1.run] Failed check base image...(from qemu-img)
  Reason: image not found
[2016.8.17 9:1:56.29][WARNING][QemuImgProc.RunningForCheckImg] Error while running 'qemu-img'. Exit value : 133
[2016.8.17 9:1:56.32][WARNING][Creator.createInternal] Failed to create the VM: Error while running 'qemu-img'. Exit value : 133
You can get more information in log file (/Users/xruiz/tizen-sdk-data/emulator/vms/emulator-manager)
[2016.8.17 9:1:56.35][WARNING][CreateVMTableViewer.createEmulator] Failed to create Emulator (w-0817-1) 
Error while running 'qemu-img'. Exit value : 133
```

Any idea of how to proceed?

Comment: Try removing .lock files if exist in tizen-sdk-data>emulator>vms. Remove logs. Also check if  necessary IDE is properly installed. If it does not work remove emulator and re-install emulator.

Comment: @enedebe - none of that helped. Is there anything else that you can suggest? I have the same error after installing tizen sdk 2.4. It looks like the root cause is this: dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libz.1.2.8.dylib. How do I install that library on Mac?

Answer (score 2):

That error happens because emulator executable (qemu-img) uses run-path (rpath) to look for dynamic libraries:

```
otool -L qemu-img 
qemu-img:
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 855.17.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 275.0.0)
@rpath/libz.1.2.8.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.8)
@rpath/libgthread-2.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 4801.0.0, current version 4801.1.0)
@rpath/libglib-2.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 4801.0.0, current version 4801.1.0)
@rpath/libintl.8.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.4.0)
/usr/lib/libutil.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
```

where @rpath is defined as:

```
Load command 23
      cmd LC_RPATH
  cmdsize 32
     path @executable_path (offset 12)
```

@executable_path in its turn has a special meaning on Mac and is not the same as a path where qemu-img is located.

To fix the problem do this:

```
cd <root>/tizen-sdk/tools/emulator/bin
install_name_tool -add_rpath "<root>/tizen-sdk/tools/emulator/bin/" qemu-img
```

where <root> is a directory where tizen-sdk is installed.

Verify that your @rpath list has been modified:

```
otool -l qemu-img
```

You should see on the bottom:

```
Load command 24
      cmd LC_RPATH
  cmdsize 56
     path <root>/tizen-sdk/tools/emulator/bin/
```

Now restart your Emulator Manager and it should work.

Another way of fixing it is to copy libraries (*.dylib) from <root>/tizen-sdk/tools/emulator/bin/ to /usr/local/lib, but be careful with this approach, do not overwrite a library if it already exists. In my case I needed to copy:

```
libglib-2.0.0.dylib
libgthread-2.0.0.dylib
libiconv.2.dylib
libintl.8.dylib
libpcre.1.dylib
libz.1.2.8.dylib
```

The second approach is risky, because it can affect other applications and I would not recommend it.

**UPDATE FOR TIZEN STUDIO**
I've just downloaded the new Tizen Studio 1.0 and found out that its emulator has the same problem. Fortunately, the same fix works for this one as well, but you need to patch two executables:

```
<root>/tizen-studio/tools/emulator/bin/qemu-img
<root>/tizen-studio/platforms/tizen-2.3.2/common/emulator/bin/emulator-x86_64
```

For the first one use the same command as for older tizen sdk (see above), for the second one use this:

```
cd <root>/tizen-studio/platforms/tizen-2.3.2/common/emulator/bin
install_name_tool -add_rpath "<root>/tizen-studio/platforms/tizen-2.3.2/common/emulator/bin" emulator-x86_64
```

**UPDATE 2019/08/16:** This problem doesn't exists in the newer versions of Tizen Studio, ver. 3+. If you still experience it, you probably have old SDK's. Delete old SDK manually and install new ones that come with Tizen Studio ver. 3+

Comment: Hey I tried to follow this for the Tizen studio and getting the same error. Please any help to it?

[2019.8.16 12:42:5.490][WARNING][QemuImgProc.running] Error while running 'qemu-img'. Exit value : 132
[2019.8.16 12:42:5.499][WARNING][Creator.createLocked] Failed to create the VM: Failed to create the VM because of failed qemu-img processing.
You can get more information in log file (/Users/vavdav/tizen-studio-data/emulator/vms/emulator-manager)

Comment: @Dawe - that fix was for older versions, i.e ver 1. After switching to ver 3 and higher I didn't see this problem anymore. I'd suggest deleting all old Tizen SDK's and installing the new version.

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled upon similar error with the Tizen Studio 1.0.2. The error is still there and suggested solution using install_name_tool worked for me.

Little tip to save you some typing:

```
cd <root>/tizen-studio/platforms/tizen-2.3.2/common/emulator/bin
install_name_tool -add_rpath $(pwd) emulator-x86_64
```